# Can't edit certain pages on DNN site after upgrade to 9.01.01

Tags: dotnetnuke, dnn9

We recently upgraded one of our client sites to 09.01.01 to address a Telerik vulnerability, and then had to migrate the site from managed.com to Azure due to manage.com's outage.  After the upgrade, a couple of pages on the site have been uneditable using the pencil icon in the persona bar, although the rest work fine.  We're aware of the workaround of going into content > pages and clicking the pencil icon there, but even then not all of the areas on the page are editable.  For example, there's one instance of the HTML module on the homepage where when you click on its pencil and then click "Edit Content," it just displays a pop-up with the text but no WYSIWYG or way to actually edit.  Other instances of the HTML module work fine, on other pages and even other areas of the homepage.

What's more bizarre is that we just spun up another Azure VM and created a dev site from a clone of the live site so we could troubleshoot further, and this problem does NOT occur on that site even though it's an exact copy of the live site files and database and both sites are hosted in Azure.

Does anyone have advice on what might be causing this or how to troubleshoot? My original though was to clone the page and start removing modules one by one to see if anything made a difference, but it doesn't actually remove the module when I click delete.  I've read about ways to do this directly in the database, but I'd prefer to avoid that if possible, especially since we're not seeing the same problem on the cloned site.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Could you please see if any error appearing on the logs folder? You can see the logs here. /Portals/_default/logs/2021.02.01.log.resources? The log file name may differ based on website's logging configuration.

A similar thing can be seen from the Personal bar as well using Admin Logs.